# Extract content of word document and insert into another word document

Tags: .net, vba, ms-word

How can I extract content of word document without headers & footers and insert it into another document with a different template(header, margins, footer are different). Can I use C# or VBA? How can I do that

Comment: Yes surely you can do it with VBA or C#.

Comment: Check Visual Studio tools for Office automation. This link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y1xatbkd(v=vs.80).aspx.

Comment: What would be the benefits of doing it in vba over c# or c# over vba

Answer (score 0):

This line will get the main document story (without headers, footers, comments, footnotes, etc.) and write it to another document:

targetDocument.Content.FormattedText = sourceDocument.Content.FormattedText

Where targetDocument and sourceDocument are two Word.Document objects.

The difference between using VBA and C# is mainly that VBA is COM and will run in-process in the Word.Application. C# is .NET and will run out-of-process. C# can be used with VSTO (which is loaded in the Word process), but can also be use via a WinForm, ConsoleApp, etc. Which you should use depends on the context of the rest of your project...